# Developing and distributing a commercial Magento extension with non-osl 3.0 licence

Tags: extensions, licensing

I'm planning on developing a commercial Magento extension following Magento's developers guide (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/) - meaning that i would extend my extensions classes from Magento's general classes, follow best practices, etc.

I would not do the following:
-physically edit any Magento's core files
-copy any code physically from core to my extension

I would only extend Magento's general classes, as advised in the guidance, and use Magento's core functions.

As i'm newbie to open source licences, i have read a LOT on open source licences, but you cannot know definitely what they (licences) mean (the more you read, the more confused you're : ) ). But because Magento and free and commercial extension developed for it are already established, there must be some sort of common wisdom on Magento, osl 3.0 and developing and distributing commercial extensions for Magento.

So my question goes as follows:
Is it common knowledge, and therefore safe to assume, that you are not creating a Derivative Work and do NOT need a dual licence (commercial Magento licence), when distributing a commercial Magento extension with non-osl 3.0 licence following the developers guide, if you are NOT physically editing, copying osl 3.0 licenced code?

Note: i'm not seeking for a legal advice as i understand that no one can say anything definitely on this issue, but i'm seeking to understand what is the common wisdom concerning this issue in Magento community, so i don't make any stupid newbie mistakes.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Relevant thread: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5819/osl3-0-magento-code-distribution

Comment: Another relevant thread: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/how-should-i-licence-my-module